# How to pass object of type LambdaExpression to methods that only accept Expression<Func<T, retT>>?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have some expressions with different return types stored in a `List<LambdaExpression>`.  I need to be able to pass these expressions to a set of methods that I don't have any control over, but that only accept arguments of type `Expression<Func<T, retT>>`.  Any ideas how I could accomplish this?  Example code below:

```
//These 3 methods are not under my control, can't change them :(
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, string>> expr) { ... }
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, int?>> expr) { ... }        
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, DateTime?>> expr) { ... }


public class Record {
    public string Member1;
    public int? Member2;
    public DateTime? Member3;
}

Expression<Func<Record, string>> expr1 = r => r.Member1;
Expression<Func<Record, int?>> expr2 = r => r.Member2;
Expression<Func<Record, DateTime?>> expr3 = r => r.Member3;

var myList = new List<LambdaExpression>() {
    expr1, expr2, expr3
};

//later...

foreach (var expr in myList)
{
    DoIt(expr); 
}
```

Comment: are you writing doit?

Comment: no, I can't change it.

Comment: MarcinJuraszek solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `dynamic`:

```
foreach (var expr in myList)
{
    DoIt((dynamic)expr); 
}
```

It will force method overload resolution to happen at runtime based on actual type of `expr`, which will work as long as there is a suitable `DoIt` method to be called.

Comment: Ah, there we go.  That worked.  Seems like `dynamic` is coming to my rescue a lot lately :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution that requires minimal code changes is to invoke dynamic overload resolution.  You lose any type safety, but it seems you already lost that anyway based on your requirements.

```
foreach (dynamic expr in myList) {
    DoIt(expr); 
}
```

This moves overload resolution from compile-time to run-time.  That means that if the resolution fails, you get a thrown exception rather than a build failure.  However, I think that drawback will be inevitable with any solution to this problem, since there are plenty of `LambdaExpression`s that aren't handled by a `DoIt` method.

Answer (score 3):

Both MarcinJuraszek's & recursive's answer are correct. Although if you want to do it without dynamic, you can do this:

```
foreach (var expr in myList)
{
    if (expr.ReturnType == typeof (string))
        DoIt((Expression<Func<Record, string>>) expr);
    else if (expr.ReturnType == typeof (int?))
        DoIt((Expression<Func<Record, int?>>) expr);
    else if (expr.ReturnType == typeof (DateTime?))
        DoIt((Expression<Func<Record, DateTime?>>) expr);
}
```